# Can't connect to mongodb using shell but can connect using compas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

From the same client, I can connect to my remote mongodb using this string:

`mongodb://siteadmin:mypassword@myip:27017`

But from the shell when I run
`mongo "mongodb://siteadmin:mypassword@myip:27017"`

```
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
root@shadow:~/website-fron
```

Any idea?

My config is simple:

```
security:
    authorization: 'enabled'
net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Was the `siteadmin` user created in the `test` database?  If no, try connecting with `mongo "mongodb://siteadmin:mypassword@myip:27017/admin"`

Comment: No it wasn't, I did "use admin" before creating it

Comment: Did that modified connection string work with the mongo shell?